# how to take out the soql from for loop

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I have wrote a batch class to update case object, based on feeditem. can some one help me to write the soql outside of for loop, am facing difficulty to do so.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
global class BatchtoUpdateBusinessDays implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public final String Query;    

    global BatchtoUpdateBusinessDays() {
        query = 'SELECT Id, Status,No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c FROM Case' +
            ' WHERE (Status != \'Closed\' AND  Status != \'Duplicate\' AND Status != \'Deleted\')';
    } 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope) {
        list<businesshours> bh  = new List<businesshours>([SELECT Id, Name FROM businesshours 
            WHERE Name = 'Working Days']);

        for(case c : scope) {
            if(bh.size() > 0) {
                String BusinessHours_Id = bh[0].Id;   
                list<Feeditem> FIlist = new list<Feeditem>([SELECT Id,parentid, CreatedDate FROM FeedItem 
                    WHERE parentId = :c.id ORDER BY createddate DESC LIMIT 1]);
                Long Mins_since_lastTouched = 
                    BusinessHours.diff(BusinessHours_Id, FIlist[0].CreatedDate, System.Now()) / 1000 / 60;
                System.debug('<<<<>>>>'+ Mins_since_lastTouched );
                c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c = Mins_since_lastTouched / 24 / 60;
                System.debug('<<<<>>>>'+ c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c );
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following could be some improvements:

1. Maps to collect Case with Feed items
2. List to collect and update only records which should be updated

Here is the updated code:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope) {
    List<BusinessHours> bh  = new List<BusinessHours>([SELECT Id, Name FROM BusinessHours 
        WHERE Name = 'Working Days']);

    // form map of Case with FeedItem
    Map<Id, FeedItem> mapCaseWithFeedItem = Map<Id, FeedItem>();
    for(FeedItem objFeedItem: [SELECT Id, ParentId, CreatedDate FROM FeedItem 
        WHERE ParentId IN :scope ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]){
        if(!mapCaseWithFeedItem.containsKey(objFeedItem.ParentId)) {
            mapCaseWithFeedItem.put(objFeedItem.ParentId, objFeedItem);
        }
    }

    // List to update only cases which needs to be modigied
    List<Case> lstCasesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
    for(Case c : scope) {
        if(bh.size() > 0 && mapCaseWithFeedItem.containsKey(c.Id)) {
            String BusinessHours_Id = bh[0].Id;   

            Long Mins_since_lastTouched = 
                BusinessHours.diff(BusinessHours_Id, 
                mapCaseWithFeedItem.get(c.Id).CreatedDate, System.Now()) / 1000 / 60;
            System.debug('<<<<>>>>'+ Mins_since_lastTouched );
            // c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c = Mins_since_lastTouched / 24 / 60;

            // add cases to updated
            lstCasesToUpdate.add(new Case(
                Id = c.Id,
                No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c = Mins_since_lastTouched / 24 / 60));
            System.debug('<<<<>>>>'+ c.No_of_Days_Case_Untchd_Business_Days__c );
        }
    }
    if(!lstCasesToUpdate.isNotEmpty()) {
        update lstCasesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: here, in this case also we are using a query in the for loop. so, will there be any difference in the code which i have written and the one you have modified??

Comment: Where do you see a query inside a for loop?

Comment: for (feeditem) -  after map collection. This wont come inside for loop? am not very sure.

Comment: Two bugs here: the earlier FeedItems will replace the latest one in `mapCaseWithFeedItem` so producing the wrong result. (Easy enough to fix.) But more problematic, by querying all the FeedItems for all the Cases in the scope you are likely to hit the "Total number of records retrieved" governor limit.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. in the above logic, i want to calculate the businesshours difference between system.now and createddate of latest feeditem of a case. but the calculation is not done accordingly..

Comment: hello keith, could you please suggest a resolution for this??

Comment: For the quick fix, updated the answer - added `containsKey` check.
Thanks @KeithC for pointing the issue. Second one is quite tricky one.

Comment: is there any other way to avoid hitting the governor limit??

Comment: You can try using a subquery (inner join SOQL query)

Comment: Hi rahul, could please explain why you have added a NOT condition in the code you have answered?if(!mapCaseWithFeedItem.containsKey(objFeedItem.ParentId))??

Comment: Didn't follow your question, can you elaborate your question